# Power BI DAX :: Comparing two columns doesn't return Yes or No

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm comparing two column in DAX:

```
RI_3years_YesNo = 
var ColTotal = SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency])
var ColRI3 = SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[RI_3years])
return
IF(ColTotal = ColRI3, "No Reservation", "Reservation")
```

The result should return 2 values `"No Reservation"` or  `"Reservation"`.

Instead is retuning only `"No Reservation"`:

[image]

Keep in mind that one of the two columns is created by this formula:

```
RI_3years = IF(ISBLANK(RELATED(Discount_Table[RI_3Years_hour])*'Usage details'[quantity]),'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency],RELATED(Discount_Table[RI_3Years_hour])*'Usage details'[quantity])
```

Comment: Do you have a .pbix to share? Are the datatypes the same?

Comment: In the image, the red note says "Two values are the same so it should return "Reservation". But your code is written to return "No reservation" if values are the same. Can you explain?

Comment: @RADO, I put a wrong note. If the two columns have the same value it should return "No reservation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this might be a rounding issue, I have stumbled across similar cases before. The values are not necessarily exactly equal prior to measure formatting being applied. Try to wrap each `SELECTEDCOLUMN` variable in a `ROUND ( .. , 2 )` to confirm.

EDIT: Upon closer inspection I believe your measure is bad.

In your screenshot it appears that you are using implicit column measures to display your values in the visualization, whereas in your measure you are using `SELECTEDVALUE` which scans the given column for a single value in the given evaluation context, and if more than one is found, returns `BLANK()`.

I believe both your variables produce `BLANK()` for all rows in your visuals, and therefore you are only seeing `No reservation` in your table. After all, both variables are `BLANK()` and the `IF` statement returns the value given in the second argument if so.

Consider adding explicit measures instead:

```
ColTotal =
    SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] )

ColRI3 =
    SUM ( 'Usage details'[RI_3years] )
```

Use these in your table visual. After this, change your original measure to use these measures instead of `SELECTEDVALUE` of the column reference. Consider rounding the two numbers if precision is an issue:

```
RI_3years_YesNo = 
VAR ColTotal = ROUND ( [ColTotal] , 2 )
VAR ColRI3 = ROUND ( [ColRI3] , 2 )
RETURN
    IF (
        ColTotal = ColRI3 , 
        "Reservation" ,  // If equal, return "Reservation"
        "No Reservation"
    )
```

This should be a fix to your question.

Comment: You did it! Thank you @Marcus.